# How to get a bold horizontal line in a long table using xltabular

Tags: tabularx, height, hline

I have a long table going over several pages and I need the last horizontal line of this table on **each** page to be bold. However, I only get the horizontal line on the very last page to be bold. Is there any solution to solve this? (Maybe similar to the head, where it works perfectly fine to have the head surrounded by bold lines on each page?)

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xltabular} 

\textheight7cm

\newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 0.8pt}} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth} {I X | X | X I} 
\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\textbf{Header column 1} & \textbf{Header column 2} & \textbf{Header column 3} \\ 
\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\endhead 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\hline 
\hline Text column 1 & Text column 2 & Text column 3 \\ 
\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\end{xltabular} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar to `\endhad` and `\endfirsthead` there are `\endfoot` and `\endlastfoot`.

Comment: You might want to use `\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\endhead
\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\endfoot`

Comment: @leandriis: Great, your solution works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `\endhead` and `\endfirsthead` there are `\endfoot` and `\endlastfoot.

In order to achieve the desired result, you might want to use

```
\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\endhead 
\noalign{\hrule height 0.8pt}
\endfoot
```